# New SharePoint sub-site is rendering incorrectly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-template, site

When I am moving a site template from our test SharePoint 2013 instance to our production SharePoint 2013 instance, the site renders incorrectly.  It almost appears as if a mobile device is trying to access a site that is not meant for mobile use.

I have tried including content, and not including content when saving the template.  I do not have any custom CSS code on the page that is trying to be displayed, so I am unsure why it would not render.